# How to centre a div in the remaining space when sliding in a div from the right

Tags: css

I have a page that will display an image (just a green div placeholder for now). I want to slide a div in from the right which will be a comments box and keep the image centred in the remaining space. If the image is too large for this remaining space I want to allow the user to scroll over the image horizontally.

I have this:

```js
var showingComments = false;

$("#clickme").click(function() {
  if (showingComments == false) {
    showingComments = true;
    $(this).parent().animate({
      right: '0px'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 500
    });
  } else {
    showingComments = false;
    $(this).parent().animate({
      right: '-150px'
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 500
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#Picture_container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#thePicture {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  /* this will change when the page loads */
  background-color: green;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#commentsBox {
  background: #00FFFF;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  right: -150px;
  top: 10px;
}

#clickme {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #5F9EA0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
}

#comments {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Picture_container'>
  picture container
  <div id='thePicture'>
    the picture goes here
  </div>
</div>

<div id="commentsBox">
  <div id="comments">
    I am a sticky-out comments box
  </div>
  <div id="clickme">
    click me!
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fwwfe2q6/

As you can see the comments box pops out but it overlaps the image holder div instead of making it move left. Can you suggest how to centre the green div (representing the image) in both the expanded and collapsed state of the comments box, and have the green div horizontally scrollable when it is too large to fit the window along with the expanded comments box?

Comment: would flex be an option ? if yes , then here is a demo https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VzoqjE

Comment: Yes, I think this will work perfectly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use flex and rethink structure:

```css
body {margin:0;}
#Picture_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 700px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: auto;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

#thePicture {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#thePicture img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 75vh;
}

p, [for="mw100"] {
  width: 100%;
  }
  p {
  background: turquoise;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

#commentsBox {
  display: flex;
  background: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#test,
#full,
#mw100 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

#commentsBox label {
  display: block;
  background: tomato;
  width: 2em;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#commentsBox label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

#clickme {
  background: purple;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: -200px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}

#test:checked~#clickme {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#full:checked~#Picture_container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#mw100:checked~img {
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="full" />
<div id='Picture_container'>
  <p>picture container <label for="full">Toggle me full or 700px width</label></p>
  <div id='thePicture'>
    <input id="mw100" type="checkbox" /><label for="mw100">toggle image overflow</label>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1800x1000/00ff00&text=the picture goes here" />
  </div>

  <div id="commentsBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
    <div id="comments">
      <label for="test">To show comments- click me!</label>
    </div>

    <div id="clickme">
      Shown comments here.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Snippet propose a few option depending on expected result.

- full width or max-width on container
- container holding image overflowing or image with max-width

labels and imputs only for demo, use js for the slidding box .

a tutorial/reminder about flex i find usefull : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is there a reason you suggest using JS for the sliding box instead of the CSS method in your demo?

Comment: @thecolin yes, this is a typical javascript job and will be solid. CSS needs to be supported and will break if HTML structure is modified, beside form element should be used in a form not instead javascript function ;) . moho